# CSS class on HTML Helper

Tags: css, html-helper

So I have this CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .DontShrink { width: 135px; }
</style>
```

There's 3 elements on the page that I want to have this width (use this class). Here's how I added it to the 3 elements:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AmortizationType,
       Chatham.Web.Models.Indications.DropDownData.AmortizationTypeDropList(),
                                                             new { @class = "DontShrink", propertyName = "AmortizationType", onchange = "UpdateField(this, false);showScheduleFields();" })%>

<%= Html.TextBox("AmortizationComponent_AmortizationEndDate", Model.AmortizationComponent.AmortizationEndDate.HasValue ? Model.AmortizationComponent.AmortizationEndDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") : "", new { @class = "DontShrink", propertyName = "AmortizationComponent.AmortizationEndDate", onchange = "parseAndSetDt(this); ", dataType = "Date" })%>

<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AmortizationRate, new { @class = "DontShrink", propertyName = "AmortizationRate", onchange = "UpdateField(this);" })%>
```

It worked for the 3rd one, but for the first two nothing happens. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed to this for the CSS:

```
.DontShrink { width: 135px !important; }
```